# How to rig this simple machine?

Tags: modeling, rigging

So i was trying to make this “unique fan”. I provided the video sample below, it’s bit low res but i think the mechanism on that machine is still readable :
[Video reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35YMK21i-M0)

> For anyone there still **unclear** or **cant see much detail** in that video,
> i just made a **simulated rig by manually keyframing it** to visualize
> better idea what im asking. Here :
>
> [Simulated Rig mechanism](https://youtu.be/kzv4XvsqrQY)

Remember, this is a manual keyframe, and i didn't want to keyframe it manually because its so inaccurate, and i wanted that ARM 2 is staying on that FAN ARM hole. So **i think rigging it is good idea**.

[image]

So i tried to recreate it, but I’m confused about how to rig it. I just did make the bones, parent the model to it. There are 2 armatures, 1 on arm, and 1 is the mechanical arm.
but i honestly no idea how to put constraints on it. Can anyone help me? this is my first rig i tried, for learning purposes.

[image]
[image]

> here is the blend file :
> https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/mt2kRaMVeA2ibumusd1lPG9egEx.blend

> here is the **simulated rig blend** file if you want to see it more
> clearly the mechanism :
> https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/zNbCDaWdyi2vwlGtAtVOqfxI3y1.blend

any help much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Chris, honestly, i am sorry, i cannot recognize from the video how the mechanism should work. Can you please provide a better quality video or explain with pictures how this should work? Thanks.

Comment: or do you mean like this: https://youtu.be/ZOvgmKNd3Js ?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. I just edited the post, i just provided the simulated rig video by using keyframe to see the mechanism. Here is the video link : https://youtu.be/kzv4XvsqrQY

Comment: By your video link, yeah it goes close from what i want, but that ARM 2 (i just named it by now so you will know which arm im talking about) is static. I want that rotate too. (like my simulated rig video). any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

As @MohammadHossein has said, it's important to have the length of the link longer than the driving arm.

I think of this as  a 2-bone IK rig, just like a character arm, if you want to look up tutorials on how to do those.

[image]

I've labelled the bones by analogy to an arm.

- The Fore Arm bone has an IK bone constraint, target: IK Target, Pole:
  IK Pole. The chain length is 2, to include the Upper arm.
- The bones, target, and pole all lie in the same plane, parallel to the floor, normal to the axes of rotation
- The IK target is parented to the rotating arm, and is the only connection between the rotating arm and the IK chain.
- The meshes do not need to be in the same plane as the bones.

The differences from a character arm are:

- It's mechanical, no need for deformation, weight-painting. Instead, the mesh-objects are directly [Bone Parented](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html#bone-parent) to their bones
- There are no poses, no disadvantage in having Empties as your IK target and IK Pole.

[image]

The rotation of the driving arm will then result in the reciprocal motion of the fan.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For this rig we should think like a mechanical engineer. we see that the driving force come from that little handle and others rotate with respect to this.

you just need something like this:

[image]

actually you need a reverse IK for your setup. keep in mind that for a clean rig you must create all of your bones in the same height which means the same `z value`.

of course the important point is to have ***good lengths*** for your arms to achieve a clean movement. *your middle arm should be **longer** than the driving arm.*

the rig could be downloaded here:

[image]